# Delete API not working in SalesForce

Tags: error

I am trying to delete user from Salesforce using sobj.delete(ids) , but I am geeting error that I do not have enough permission to delete. I have system admin profile . Please let me know if I need to do any update in my Sales Force account setting.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete User in Salesforce .You can only deactivate a User .Before you deactivate consider all implications

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=deactivating_users.htm

Comment: Thanks Mohith for quick reply :) Just inqusitive to know why SalesForce expose delete API if users can't be deleted.

Comment: Only Users cant be deleted while other records can be deleted .Like you can delete account,contact or any other object data

Comment: I have one more question, if you can help me out. I am trying to update UserLicense Id aginst User Profile , but I am getting error Message that filed is not available for create/update.